# Derivation Treynor-Black model

Tags: portfolio-optimization, sharpe-ratio, treynor-black

In the treynor-black model the assumption is that markets are not fully optimal and it is possible to achieve additional alpha on top of the market portfolio. After a mean-variance optimization treynor-black model arrives at optimal weights for the active portfolio $w_A$
and $(1-w_A)$ is the allocation to the market portfolio.

$w_0 = \frac{\frac{\alpha_A}{\sigma_A^2(e)}}{\mu_m/\sigma^2_m}$

$w_A = \frac{w_0}{1+(1-B)w_0}$

I have troubles understanding the statement that the squared sharpe ratio of the full portfolio (containing w_A of the active portfolio and (1-w_A) of the market portfolio) equals the sum of the squared sharpe ratios, i.e.:

$Sp^2 =\{\frac{expectedreturn}{vola} \}^2=  \frac{\mu^2}{\sigma_m^2} + \frac{\alpha^2}{\sigma_A^2(e)}$

Below link gives a more detailed description of the problem.
But it is also described in identical way in the book of Bodie, Kane, Marcus "investments".
https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1576276/FULLTEXT02.pdf

Comment: The return on the securities is $R_i=\alpha_i+\beta_i R_M + e_i$ where the $e_i$ are uncorrelated with each other and with $R_M$. This uncorrelation is what allows you to write the "sum of squared ratios" expression that you have.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I don't fully follow your argumentation.
$R_A = \alpha_A + \beta R_m + \epsilon$. And as you correctly point out epsilon and $R_m$ are uncorrelated. Ret of portfolio $R_{port}= $w_A$ R_A +$(1-w_A)$ R_m$. It therefore has variance equal to $w_A^2 (\beta^2 \sigma_m^2 + \sigma_A^2) + (1-w_A)^2*\sigma_m^2 + 2w_A(1-w_A)\beta\sigma_m^2$.

The sharpe of my portfolio = $\frac{w_A * (\alpha_A + \beta \mu) + (1-w_A)\mu}{w_A^2 (\beta^2 \sigma_m^2 + \sigma_A^2) + (1-w_A)^2*\sigma_m^2 + 2w_A(1-w_A)\beta\sigma_m^2}$. How do you split the terms after squaring?